# Function of meshgrid numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have a problem where I want to plot the determinant of a matrix as a function of parameters, so I have a script

```
def f(x, y):

    DD = np.matrix([[0., 0.],[0., 0.]]) + 0.j
    omega = x + 1.j * y

    # set up dispersion matrix
    DD[0,0] = 1 + omega
    DD[1,0] = omega
    DD[0,1] = omega
    DD[1,1] = 1 - omega

    metric = np.linalg.det(DD)

    return metric

xx = np.arange(1., 2., 0.1)
yy = np.arange(1., 2., 0.1)

x, y = np.meshgrid(xx, yy)


FPlot = f(x, y)

plt.contourf(x, y, FPlot)
plt.show()
```

There is a type error where, since omega is a meshgrid, I can't stick it into the matrix or compute the determinant -- numpy demands scalars in matrices. What's the best way around this to get the right mesh and evaluated determinants?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `np.frompyfunc`:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def f(x, y):

    DD = np.matrix([[0., 0.],[0., 0.]]) + 0.j
    omega = x + 1.j * y

    # set up dispersion matrix
    DD[0,0] = 1 + omega
    DD[1,0] = omega
    DD[0,1] = omega
    DD[1,1] = 1 - omega

    metric = np.linalg.det(DD)

    return metric
f = np.frompyfunc(f, 2, 1)

xx = np.arange(1., 2., 0.1)
yy = np.arange(1., 2., 0.1)
x, y = np.meshgrid(xx, yy)

FPlot = f(x, y)

plt.contourf(x, y, FPlot)  # Note that this is only using the real part of FPlot
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Haven't seen that function before, and that fixed it! Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

IF you have the brand new numpy 1.8, you can use one of its cool new features: linear algebra gufuncs. Basically, when you call `np.linalg.det`, it will compute the determinant over the last two dimensions for any shape array you pass in:

```
xx = np.arange(1., 2., 0.1)
yy = np.arange(1., 2., 0.1)

x, y = np.meshgrid(xx, yy)
omega = x + 1.j * y

dispersion_matrices = np.empty(omega.shape + (2, 2), dtype=omega.dtype)
dispersion_matrices[..., 0, 0] = 1 + omega
dispersion_matrices[..., 1, 0] = omega
dispersion_matrices[..., 0, 1] = omega
dispersion_matrices[..., 1, 1] = 1 - omega
FPlot = np.linalg.det(dispersion_matrices)

plt.contourf(x, y, FPlot.imag) # the part missing in unutbus's plot!
plt.show()
```

[image]